# need assistance on react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and I am having trouble passing an array as props

in this function I am requesting data from the flickr api to display photos, I used setState to **cats** to hold that data array

```
//this function will retrieve the CATS pictures

   renderCats = () => {
    //fetch data from flickr
    axios 
      .get(
        ` https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${apiKey}&tags=cats&per_page=24&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
      )
      .then(response => { //set the response so that pics will be equal to the data array containing cat photos from flickr
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          cats: response.data.photos.photo, 
          loading: false //initialize a loading state to display a loading message
        });
      })
      .catch(error => { //this catch method outputs a message to the console, should axios fail to retrieve data
        console.log("Something went wrong, could not access data", error);
      });
  };
```

then in the render() I am trying to use the code snippet below, where /cats is my nav link, and I am trying to render a component called Cats, but at the same time I am trying to pass the data array by using data={this.state.cats}

```
 <Route path="/cats" render={ <Cats data={this.state.cats} /> } />
```

also this is what I have at the top of my App component, where I am using super() this.state for cats: [], I think the reason I am struggling is because I am getting mixed up between this.state and this.setState, any helpful tips to improve my code will be appreciated

```
class App extends Component { //Class components need to extend  React.Component, and class components require the render()
   constructor() {
     //state for data we want to display from flickr
     super();
     this.state = {
       pics: [], //this array will hold the pictures that will render as soon as the page loads
       cats: [],
       loading: true
     };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.performSearch(); //call performSearch function on the componentDidMount() life cycle
     this.renderCats()
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in how you pass the props. In your example,

`<Route path="/cats" render={ <Cats data={this.state.cats} /> } />`

The data prop would essentially be ignored. However, if you pass it like this:

```
<Route
  path="/cats"
  render={(props) => <Cats {...props} data={this.state.cats} />}
/>
```

You'll have access to it. However, to keep things simpler, might I suggest moving the actual data fetch function inside the component that needs it? This way, if you're fetching let's say 20 different things, like cats, dogs, mice, depending on your setup, you'd render block the entire application for data you may or may not need.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine, except that the `render` prop on `Route` [needs to be a function](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#render-func).

```js
 <Route path="/cats" render={ () => <Cats data={this.state.cats} /> } />
```

If you don't need it to be a function, you can use `component` instead:

```js
 <Route path="/cats" component={ <Cats data={this.state.cats} /> } />
```